# How to remove an unfavorited post from my Stack Exchange overall favorites?

Tags: bug, bookmarks, network-profile, profile-sync

Sometimes when I unfavorite a post, it still appears in my Stack Exchange favorites (which shows favorites across all SE network sites).

This is clearly a bug, but I don't know how to fix it. Clicking on "Sync with oldest profile" doesn't fix it; favoriting and unfavoriting again doesn't fix it.

So what else can I do to try and fix this?

Comment: Can't do that, only a dev can. If you think it's something urgent (e.g. question you really don't want others to know you favorited) send a request [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/contact) for a faster response.

Comment: Thanks. I'll keep that in mind, although right now it's not urgent. I find that unfavoriting the post and favoriting it again, sometimes while syncing my SE profile in between, will fix the problem. But it's not a consistent enough solution since it doesn't always work.

Comment: Better way to force synch is performing "real" action on the site you want to be synchronized e.g. posting question or answer.

Comment: I'm still having this problem constantly. Performing a "real" action isn't the best solution since I'd just be spamming the site. Although I guess I could just keep deleting my posts afterward. But it'd be nice if the "sync" button actually worked.

Comment: The "Sync with oldest profile" is not relevant, it only synchronize the profile data: country, website, age, and "about me" section. (maybe avatar as well)

Comment: Oh really? Well that helps. So there really is no way to sync Favorites? The only way is to post a comment on every Stack Exchange site where I have a favorited post? Or is posting on one site enough?

Comment: No no, it should be synchronized by itself, only on rare occasions it might fail then some other event can fix it.

Comment: My Favorites fail to sync with my overall Stack Exchange account pretty often though. Like once a week or more, at the very least. Primarily, adding favorites is not a problem. But removing them is difficult. Favorites I removed a long time ago are still there.